# Leistungsaufnahme vs. Stromverbrauch?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ist das Wort *Leistungsaufnahme* gleichbedeutend mit *Stromverbrauch*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Stromverbrauch" wird meist für eine Energiegröße benutzt (Joule J oder Kilowattstunde kWh), also das, was in der Stromrechnung steht.

Auf einen konkreten Verbraucher bezogen wird der Begriff aber auch für die Leistungsaufnahme eines Gerätes benutzt (Watt W oder Kilowatt kW).

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Stromverbrauch) gibt eine physikalisch nicht besonders sinnvolle, neutrale Definition ("Verbrauch von elektrischem Strom") hat Beispiele für beide Gebräuche und nennt als Synonyme sowohl "Bedarf an elektrischer Energie" als auch "Leistungsaufnahme".

Wikipedia leitet den Begriff "Stromverbrauch" auf das Lemma "Bedarf an elektrischer Energie" weiter.

Nutzung in Sinn von "Energieverbrauch":

> "Wenn ich mit diesem Gerät 10 Minuten meine Haare trockne, bedeutet das einen Stromverbrauch von 0,2 kWh."

Nutzung im Sinn von "Leistungsaufnahme":

> "Der Stromverbrauch dieses Haartrockners ist 1200 Watt."

Das ist äquivalent zu

> "Die Leistungaufnahme dieses Haartrockners ist 1200 Watt."

Das Wort "Leistungsaufnahme" ist ein technischer Fachbegriff, im Alltag würden es nur wenige Menschen benutzen und vielleicht auch nicht jeder verstehen.

Hier ein Beispiel, das das Wort "Stromverbrauch" in einem Absatz mit beiden verschiedenen Bedeutungen benutzt:

> "Der Stromverbrauch des Raspberry Pi 3 liegt im Leerlauf und bei niedriger CPU-Auslastung laut Messung bei 1,22 Watt, bei aktiver Nutzung können es 3 Watt sein. Der Stromverbrauch eines Raspberry Pi 3 pro Jahr liegt bei einem dauerhaften Betrieb bei ca. 26 Kilowattstunden (kWh)." ([Quelle](https://www.energie.web.de/ratgeber/verbrauch/stromverbrauch-rasperry/))

Comment: Diese Antwort ist falsch. [Die Antwort von vokstudent](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71540/1487) ist hingegen korrekt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast technisch betrachtet ist dein Kommentar absolut richtig. (Umgangs-)sprachlich ist diese Antwort jedoch korrekt.

Answer (score 5):

Nein. No.

Leistungsaufnahme[W]

Stromverbrauch [Ws] or [Wh]

Stomverbrauch = Leistungsaufnahme x Zeit

Dt. : Wenn du beispielsweise einen Haartrockner mit einer Leistungsaufnahme von 1000 Watt eine Stunde lang benutzt, dann verbrauchst du 1kWh = 3600kWs= 3600000 Ws

---

Eng. : For example if your hairdryer has a Leistungsaufnahme of 1000 Watt and you use it for 1 hour, then  it consumes 1kWh = 3600kWs= 3600000 Ws.

Comment: Danke vielmal! Das hat mir sehr geholfen:)

Comment: @vukstudent: Deine Antwort ist zwar absolut korrekt, aber du könntest sie noch verbessern, wenn du Quellen hinzufügst, die belegen, dass die Begriffe tatsächlich so verwendet werden, wie du es behauptest. Es ist auch nicht notwendig, die Antwort (oder Teile davon) in eine Fremdsprache zu übersetzen. Zum Thema "in welcher Sprache soll ich eine Antwort schreiben" findest du hier etwas: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487